# How to perform union operation between two tables?

Tags: mysql, c

After performing union operator between two tables in which the columns in one of the table are empty  the result is displaying from second row... i dont why why is this happening ...? can anyone clarify my doubt?

my tables are sample1 and sample2
Both table contains Id, Empname , Location

data in table is

```
  101    Null    NUll
  102    aaaa   sec
```

data in table2 is

```
  103    bbbb    hyd
  102    cccc    gdv
```

Query:

```
    (select EmpName,Location
    from sample1)
    union
    (select EmpName,Location
    from sample2) 


Output
  EMPNAME         LOCATION

    aaaa          sec
    bbbb           hyd
    cccc           gdv
```

Comment: Show some examples please...

Comment: show us the query, its possible that the where clause in your query for second table is true with condition so its fetching the data from the second table

Comment: As @RagingBull says, without more info, you are just leaving us to guess.

Comment: hi guys now i have given the full information

Comment: the first row is empty because it has just null values... try to add WHERE EmpName IS NOT NULL to your 2 selects.

Comment: @user3531533: I get [**this result**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ea52/3) with your query. Isn't it the expected output?

Comment: As said already you should add your actual query results and the one you are expecting so someone can explain the actual behaviour to you.
Probably (as I understand your question right) UNION ALL will do the trick for you, but that's just a guess so far.

Comment: In the output the first row is shown empty..i just wanted to eliminate that roe.. @RagingBull

Comment: I have tried your code but of no use the result is same ... @Ranging Bull

Comment: show your sample output

Comment: i have posted my output above @SATSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the null records from the result, try this:

```
(select EmpName,Location
from sample1
WHERE EmpName IS NOT NULL
  AND Location IS NOT NULL)
union 
(select EmpName,Location
from sample2
WHERE EmpName IS NOT NULL
  AND Location IS NOT NULL)
```

Result:

```
EMPNAME   LOCATION
vijay     ngdv
suresh    hyd
ajay      hyd
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ea52/11).

**EDIT:**

I guess the record contains empty string or white spaces instead of null. So try this:

```
(select EmpName,Location
from sample1
WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(EmpName)) >0
  AND LENGTH(TRIM(Location)) >0)
union 
(select EmpName,Location
from sample2
WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(EmpName)) >0
  AND LENGTH(TRIM(Location)) >0)
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59d93/2).

**Explanation:**

`LENGTH(TRIM(EmpName))` will return the length of the field `EmpName` after removing white spaces from it.

Comment: I have tried your code but of no use the result is same ... @Ranging Bull

Comment: @user3531533: Do you have any more fields in the select query?

Comment: @user3531533: Which table the null values are selected from? sample1 or sample2?

Comment: @user3531533: Execute only the first part .ie., sample1 only with where clause. What is the result?

Comment: I have tried u r method i have executed first part only...its showing null row even now..

Comment: @user3531533: Yes, I am. In fact, it doesn't matter mysql or SQL Server. This query would work fine in almost all RDBMSs.

Comment: is there any other option other than union @Raging Bull

Comment: I got the answer with previous one... Thank you very much

Comment: Problem with data in database the field is saved as blank but not null.. thats a small issue . I had realised it lately..

Comment: @user3531533: For such cases, you can use the second query in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**How to perform union operation between two tables?**

you have to use union operator with following circumstances,

1.You have similar information in multiple tables and you want to retrieve rows from all of 
  them at once.

2.You want to select several sets of rows from the same table, but the conditions that 
  characterize each set aren't easy to write as a single WHERE clause. UNION allows retrieval 
  of each set with a simpler WHERE clause in its own SELECT statement; the rows retrieved by 
  each are combined and produced as the final query result.

Note : its not the perfect answer for your question but it helps in understanding of union 
       operator

please see this http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Funtions-and-Operators/How-does-union-work-in-MySQL